# RHEL7.7 How do I run "debuginfo-install kernel" when using a local repo that is an iso mounted locally?

Tags: linux, kernel, rhel7, crash

I want to use "crash" to look at the kernel core.

crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules//vmlinux  /var/crash//vmcore

But /usr/lib/debug/lib is empty and it looks like that directory (debug libraries) is populated with "debuginfo-install kernel"

I have the iso mount on /mnt/disc and yum recognizes the repo.

## yum repolist all

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id                                            repo name                                                           status
InstallMedia                                       Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.7                                        enabled: 5,229
repolist: 5,229

However when I try the following it seems to want/need a subscription-manager registration:

## debuginfo-install kernel

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: kernel-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install

OR

## debuginfo-install kernel --enablerepo=InstallMedia

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: kernel-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install

How do I install the kernel debuginfo packages from the iso repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iso image or a DVD try the below step to have it mount and 
install packages in the local system.

## mkdir -p  /mnt/disc

## mount -o loop RHEL7.1.iso /mnt/disc

```
If you use DVD media , you can mount like below.

# mkdir -p  /mnt/disc
# mount /dev/sr0  /mnt/disc

Copy the media.repo file from the root of the mounted directory to /etc/yum.repos.d/ and set the permissions to 0644 or another similar permissions set:


# cp /mnt/disc/media.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7dvd.repo
# chmod 644 /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7dvd.repo

Edit the new repo file, changing the gpgcheck=0 setting to 1 and adding the following 3 lines


vi /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7dvd.repo
enabled=1
baseurl=file:///mnt/disc/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

In the end, the new repo file could look like the following


[InstallMedia]
name=DVD for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1 Server
mediaid=1359576196.686790
metadata_expire=-1
gpgcheck=1
cost=500
enabled=1
baseurl=file:///mnt/disc/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

Clear the cache and check whether you can get the packages list from the DVD repo

# yum clean all
# yum repolist enabled

It should look like the following if no other repository is enabled.
To avoid any corruption its recommend to disable any non-redhat repositories.
```

## yum repolist enabled

Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id                                                                                 repo name
InstallMedia                                                                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.7 
repolist: 5,229

```
If no errors are returned, the following can be used to update:

# yum update
```